# Show that cosh(2) is between two values.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm reviewing for exams and this question has got me stumped:

#### Show that:

---

$3\dfrac{2}{3} \leq \cosh(2) \leq 3\dfrac{2}{3} + 0.1$

---

I've determined the series form of cosh(x) to be:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$

And I can tell that the question ultimately wants me to evaluate cosh(2) to 1 decimal accuracy - any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: $$3\frac{2}{3}<3\frac{2}{3}+\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{2^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\cosh(2)$$ And the second inequality isn't true, as pointed out by "julien".

Comment: @Ethan:  Correct.  That gets one of the inequalities.

Comment: I copied it straight from a sample exam, I suppose they aren't as rigorous as one would think.

Comment: @kvmu I am sorry. The inequality is indeed true as we can check if we enter the appropriate numbers in a calculator...

Answer (score 1):

(I tried to find a way to use the definition of hyperbolic cosine to establish the inequality, but it seems to be difficult to make both limits "tight enough".)  Instead, if you write out the first six terms of the Maclaurin series (and only simplify the first few), you get

$$\cosh 2 =  1 + \frac{4}{2} + \frac{16}{24} + \frac{64}{720} + \frac{64 \cdot 4}{720 \cdot 7 \cdot 8} +   \frac{64 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 }{720 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10} + \ldots $$

$$=  \frac{11}{3} + \frac{4}{15} + \frac{4 \cdot 4}{15 \cdot 7 \cdot 8} +   \frac{4 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 }{15 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10} + \ldots ,$$

with the $\frac{11}{3}$ coming from the first three terms.  You want to look for a  suitable ratio for a geometric series that will be "just larger" than the terms beyond $\frac{11}{3}$.  See what that series sums up to...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Since all the terms in the series are positive, once you have added enough to be greater than $3\frac23$ you can never fall below.  Then you need to justify that the remaining terms will not take you above the upper limit.  The easiest way is to bound the tail below a geometric series that you can evaluate.

Comment: How do I go about finding a comparison for the factorial (to bound the tail)?

Comment: Write out what the next two or three terms of the Maclaurin series for $\cosh 2$ are beyond $(1 + 2 + \frac{2}{3})$.  See if that suggests a geometric series you could write that is close but definitely larger than all the remaining terms in the Maclaurin series.  (Don't actually multiply out the values of the Maclaurin terms; just see what additional factors appear in the numerators and denominators.)

Comment: @kvmu:   [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) will get you there.